# k6 metrics to influx for grafana

Tags: grafana, k6

Scenario: running a k6 scenario with multiple api calls.

Need to populate a dashboard in grafana for results from k6 which shows count status code by api call, need a graphs plotting average time taken by each api in scenario during the k6 run

Information is pushed to influxDb and then populated on grafana dashboard

Comment: k6 already has builtin support for [InfluxDB outputs](https://k6.io/docs/results-visualization/influxdb-+-grafana). Is your question how to use this output or how to create the Grafana dashboards? Where exactly are you stuck with your task?